# filling colors in cubes in a 3D checkerboard lattice using asymptote

Tags: color, asymptote, lattice

I used the following code from [another tikz question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270410/32412) to create a 3D lattice

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=3dgrid}
settings.render=8;
settings.outformat='png';
size(200);
import graph3;

int L=4;
triple s;
currentprojection=perspective(27,19,11);
real r = 0.1;
surface site = scale3(r)*unitsphere;
real dist = 1.5;

for(int i=1;i<=L;++i)
{
for(int j=1;j<=L;++j)
{
for(int k=1;k<=L;++k)
{
  s=dist*(i,j,k);
  draw(shift(s)*site,red);
  if (i < L) draw(shift(s) * (O -- (dist-r)*X),
          p=blue+0.7pt);
  if (j < L) draw(shift(s) * (O -- (dist-r)*Y),
          p=gray+0.7pt);
  if (k < L) draw(shift(s) * (O -- (dist-r)*Z),
          p=green+0.7pt);
 }
 }
 }
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I also want to fill in colors inside the cubes in a checkerboard pattern. Is there an easy way to do that?

Edit: I realize I can use the draw(unitcube,blue)) but can one extend this to cuboids?

Comment: I realize I can use the 
draw(unitcube,blue)) but can one extend this to cuboids?

Comment: It's a good idea to link the "other tikz question" to give proper credit to the original author of the code.

Comment: @user25957 maybe draw(shift(A)*xscale(r)*yscale(s)*unitcube,blue)). Moreover, I am not sure I understand about this " *inside the cubes in a checkerboard pattern*"

Comment: "inside the cubes in a checkerboard pattern" means color alternates --let one cube be black, then all of the neighbors that share a face with it are white and vice-versa.

Comment: @user25957 Oh, I got what you want to draw. It is not difficult in programming with Asymptote. I am a bit curious in which context that kind of figure arises