# Path shaded perpendicular to its direction

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

Is ist possible to apply a shading to a path perpendicular to it's current tangent.

I want to draw some kind of 3d-pipe. My question is related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176298/). I want to draw 3d-molecules and I am struggeling with how to draw the bonds between the atoms.

I'd like to have something like

`\draw[bond color=red; bond width=15pt] (atom1) -- (atom2);`

The result should be a pole from coordinate `atom1` to coordinate `atom2`. Pole means a rectangle with a length of the distance beween `atom1` and `atom2` and a height of 15pt filled with a shade red-white-red along the height axis.

I could actually do that using `\shade` and `shading angle` but then I'd have to calculate the shading angle myself depending on the coordinates of `atom1` and `atom2`.

Any suggestions for that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you fill in the missing details with the code and possibly the wrong output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally a dedicated decoration could be used (similar to the one that the `mindmap` library provides for connecting concepts), but here is a simple example using the `show path construction` decoration.

The shading is applied manually to (a) illustrate how it can be done (b) bypass the default process of clipping the shading to the center quarter.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\colorlet{bar.top}{red}
\colorlet{bar.bottom}{blue}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading[bar.top,bar.bottom]{shaded.bar}{100bp}{
color(0bp)=(bar.bottom);color(100bp)=(bar.top)}

\tikzset{shading bar/.style args={#1 thick from #2 to #3}{
  decoration={show path construction,
  lineto code={
    \pgfscope%
    %
    % Set the colors.
    \colorlet{bar.top}{#2}%
    \colorlet{bar.bottom}{#3}%
    %
    % Manually apply the shading.
    % As the bar is a rectangle, scale the shading (which is 100bp x 100bp).
    % Other bar shapes would other adjustments before applying the shading.
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentfirst}%
    \pgftransformrotate{\pgfdecoratedangle}%
    \pgftransformxscale{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100bp}%
    \pgftransformyscale{#1/100bp}%
    %
    % Although the shading is a (scaled) rectangle the
    % bounding box needs to be updated to the correct size
    % which is done here using clipping.
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfqpoint{0bp}{-50bp}}{\pgfqpoint{100bp}{100bp}}%
    \pgfusepath{clip}% 
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{50bp}{0bp}}%   
    \pgflowlevelsynccm%
    \pgfuseshading{shaded.bar}%
    \endpgfscope%
  }}, decorate
}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (5,5);
\draw [shading bar=5mm thick from red to orange] (0,0) -- (3,2);     
\draw [shading bar=5mm thick from blue to cyan] (0,2) -- (2,5); 
\draw [shading bar=10mm thick from green to yellow] (3,5) -- (5,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your really helpful answer. I could modify your code in a way that it suits my needs.