# Are there packages to plot space group diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, diagrams, pstricks

Space group diagrams are used in crystallography for visual representation of symmetries a particular crystal has. These diagrams include a great deal of specific symbols that I'm not keen on redrawing. You can see an example of a space group diagram below: 
[image: A space group diagram for a Pnma group. Birkbeck college, University of London.]

Here's an easier example:

[image: A space group diagram for a P2c group. Birkbeck college, University of London.]

Are there tikz or pstricks packages that are suited specifically for crystallographic applications?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97271/  http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&p=70311  https://istitov.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/drawing-the-crystal-lattice-in-latex/

Comment: Very related: https://github.com/GeekMe93/Crystallography

Comment: see package `pst-gr3d` which can also be used for 2d grids